# What is the best way to test Alexa Skills locally (Python)?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm developing Alexa skills in python and it's time wasting to go and deploy any minor code change to AWS Lambda using it's console or via AWS CLI and search for logs in CloudWatch .

I want to know what would be the least time consuming method to test any code change that I do locally without needing to deploy the code to AWS lambda .

Basically I want to test the lambda function locally .

Comment: I know there are certain tools for JS like Bespoken , BST etc but I'm not sure how to use them with Python Lambda functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Alexa skill that I'm creating now is just a lambda function in python, python-lambda-local is the package to test lambda function locally .

For steps on how to configure PyCharm to run lambda function locally ,please check this [post](https://medium.com/@bezdelev/how-to-test-a-python-aws-lambda-function-locally-with-pycharm-run-configurations-6de8efc4b206) .